# Ruby Extended Array class that supports full method chain

Tags: arrays, ruby, oop, inheritance

**Short:**

Is there a way to create extended `Array` class named `A`, that supports full method chain with `map`, `sort`, `sort_by` and new method `word` and does not harm `Array` class?

Example:

```
 [
    A.new(a).word,
    A.new(a).sort.word,
    A.new(a).sort_by(&:-@).word,
    A.new(a).map(&:chr).sort.map(&:ord).word
  ]
```

**Long story:**

I solved this [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sort-and-transform/ruby) and created code that extends `Array` class with new `word` method:

```
class Array
  def word
    [*self[0..1],*self[-2..-1]].map(&:chr).join
  end
end
def sort_transform(a)
  [
    a.word,
    a.sort.word,
    a.sort_by(&:-@).word,
    a.map(&:chr).sort.map(&:ord).word
  ].join ?-
end
```

Then I thought this is not a good idea to add method for such kind of base classes. And I tried to implement new class that inherited all behavior from an `Array`.

```
class A < Array
  def word
    [*self[0..1],*self[-2..-1]].map(&:chr).join
  end
end
```

This addition breaks my code, because `map`, `sort`, `sort_by` returns an `Array` instance: `A.new([1,2,3]).sort.class # Array`. And Array does not understand a `word` method. And instead of `A.new(a).sort.word` I have to encapsulate part of chain into a `A.new` constructor: `A.new(a.sort).word`. That's definitely breaks **pure** method chain.

Is it possible to extend `Array` such way to reach pure method chains like this; `A.new(a).sort.word`?

When I tried to write line this:
class A < Array

```
def word
    [*self[0..1],*self[-2..-1]].map(&:chr).join
  end
  def sort
    A.new(self.sort)
  end
end
```

This brings me `main.rb:8:in 'sort': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`
Finally already writing this lines I found a way to avoid deep stack: converting self to `Array` and then again convert it to `A`.

```
class A < Array
  def word
    [*self[0..1],*self[-2..-1]].map(&:chr).join
  end
  def sort
    A.new(self.to_a.sort)
  end
end
```

So is It an only way to implement such extension?

Comment: The article was given to me https://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes 
And developer who gave me this article told that instances cast back to `Array` in method chain in `Ruby` because of `C` code.  
It implements for speed.

Comment: I'd use a refinement on `Array` instead. Why does no-one use refinements?

Comment: @Amadan this why I wrote this question :) To get information you gave.

Comment: Why would you add an instance method to `Array`, subclass `Array` or refine `Array`. Why not just define a method `word` with one argument for the given array?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Why would you not refine? That's why they're _for_. Why refine over a function? Because it chains better, and chaining reads more naturally since it linearly represents causality. `f.each_line.map(&:length).max` has flow. `find_max(get_lines(f).map(&:length))` goes back and forth and incurs a higher mental load. The non-parallelism between syntax and execution order is one of the reasons why I dislike Python: why is `len` a function but `lower` a method but `map` a function but `join` a method on _string_ but `sorted` a function but `sort` a method... And comprehensions... >.<

Comment: @Amadan, your argument is compelling. Nice answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever want to monkey-patch a core class but you think it's icky, you should remember that refinements are made just for this scenario.

```
module ArrayWithWord
  refine Array do
    def word
      [*self[0..1],*self[-2..-1]].map(&:chr).join
    end
  end
end

class WordTest
  using ArrayWithWord

  # [].word works here
  def self.sort_transform(a)
    [
      a.word,
      a.sort.word,
      a.sort_by(&:-@).word,
      a.map(&:chr).sort.map(&:ord).word
    ].join ?-
  end
end

WordTest.sort_transform(%w(foo bar baz quux))
# => "fbbq-bbfq-bbfq-bbfq"

# [].word doesn't work here
[].word
# => NoMethodError (undefined method `word' for []:Array)
```